# Store array of string into the mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am very new to `MongoDB` and `mongoose` I have a model name called `agent`

**agent.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const agentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    agent: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Agent = mongoose.model('Agent', agentSchema)

module.exports = Agent;
```

Now I have a array of string:

```
const agentName = ['john', 'alex', 'david'];
```

Now I want to store this array into the mongoDB as an individual agent.

like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6000977d9b94f52960955066",
        "agent": "john",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6000977d9b94f52960955067",
        "agent": "alex",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6000977d9b94f52960955068",
        "agent": "david",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Note: Right now First I am converting my array of string into the array of object using loop like this:

```
agentName = agentName.map((e) => {return {agent: e}})
```

//output of above line of code

```
[ { agent: 'Alex Watson' },
  { agent: 'John Snow' },
  { agent: 'Rita Ora' } ]
```

Then I am saving the agentName.

**But I am looking for some better approach, Like in which there is no need of converting the array of string into the array of object.**

Answer (score 1):

you must to use `insertMany()` function is used to insert multiple documents into a collection. It accepts an `array of documents` to insert into the collection. like following code, so have to create a array of abjects, that you created

**note:** in your question define `const agentName` next step assign result of map to the constant variable, so this is wrong

```
const agentName = ['john', 'alex', 'david'];
let arr = agentName.map((e) => {return {agent: e}})

Agent.insertMany(arr).then(function(){ 
    console.log("Data inserted")  // Success 
}).catch(function(error){ 
    console.log(error)      // Failure 
});
```